# php - move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move

Tags: php, file, upload, directory, temp

I am trying to use `move_uploaded_file` like this:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1'.$username]['tmp_name'], 'images') && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file0'.$username]['tmp_name'], 'images')) {

...
```

I get the error:

```
move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpHNeWpt' to 'images' in /home1/eamondev/public_html/sneekback/respond.php on line 99
```

I have tried changing the permissions of the `images` folder to `777` and that didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just specify the directory you are moving the file to, you have to enter the name you are going to call the file in that directory:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file0']['tmp_name'], __DIR__.'/images/'.basename($_FILES['file0']['name'])
```